# Ayuda Para controlar primera ejecución de un programa hecho en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

estoy haciendo un proyecto en netbeans y quiero hacer que cuando mi programa se ejecute por primera vez o después de la instalación  muestre una ventana para registrar al primer usuario en la base de datos, solo quiero saber como puedo hacer la parte para controlar si el programa se ejecuta por primera vez.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un archivo para guardar este tipo de detalles, así lo hacen algunas aplicaciones.

```
public final class AppUtils {
  private final static String PATH = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.tuapp";

  public static void writeConfigFile() {
    String data = "configured: 1";

    Files.write(Paths.get(AppUtils.PATH), data.getBytes());
  }

  public static boolean isFirstExecution() {
    return !new File(AppUtils.PATH).exists();
  }
}
```

Cuando cargue tu frame, verificas si es primera ejecución (el archivo no existe) y actúas de acuerdo a ello:

```
if (AppUtils.isFirstExecution()) {
  // mostrar un panel para registrar un usuario
  // o hacerlo directamente mediante la DAO
} else {
  // cargar otro frame
}
```

Otra opción es que tengas en tu base de datos una tabla para configuraciones, es mucho más seguro, así evitas que accidetalmente se borre el archivo (no es común, pero posible).

Comment: Hola Gustavo García, gracias por tu respuesta, pero me  muestra un error en la línea: return !File.exist(PATH)       El error dice: method exists in class File cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: Reemplaza `PATH` por `AppUtils.PATH` ya que es una variable estática.

Comment: Ya lo reemplaze y me sigue mostrando el mismo error

Comment: Código corregido @BrynnerFlores.

Comment: Bien bro, ya no muestra error, voy a seguir probando con tu código

Answer (score 0):

Buenas

Como comenta el compañero [Gustavo García](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/26302/gustavo-garc%C3%ADa): 
Crear un fichero  que uses como referencia para saber si el programa ya ha sido ejecutado con anterioridad.

Como mejora, podrías crear este documento solo cuando haya pasado la validación de registrar el usuario. Esto evitaría los problemas (siempre y cuando el usuario o sistema no borre accidentalmente el archivo).

Saludos